# Erro Classe não encontrada com Composer

Tags: php, classes, composer, php-autoload

Boas pessoal, seguinte, to fazendo um projeto aqui e da me dando uns problemas, acho que estou misturando as coisas.

Instalei o composer para utilizar o autoload e outra dependencias, mas agora estou com um problema:

O erro que me dá é o seguinte:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Base' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cadUsuario.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cadUsuario.php on line 8
```

Os arquivos estão assim:

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.1",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~5.2"
},
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {"Photobooker\\": "class/"}
}
```

As minhas classes são, Base e Conexao:

**Base**:

```
<?php
namespace Photobooker;
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
$db = Conexao::getInstance();
```

**Conexao**:

```
namespace Photobooker;

class Conexao
{

    private static $pdo;

    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        $conn = require(__DIR__ . '/../dbconfig.php');
        if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$conn[host]; dbname=$conn[dbname]", $conn['user'], $conn['pass']);
                self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$conn[host]; dbname=$conn[dbname]", $conn['user'], $conn['pass']);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }

        return self::$pdo;
    }
}
```

o arquivo que chama isso tudo se chama `cadUsuario.php` e está iniciado assim:

```
<?php

require "vendor/autoload.php";

$pdo = Base::getInstance($db, "usuario");
```

O `autoload` ali não deveria chamar a classe `Base`?

---

Alterei o seguinte:

em cadUsuario:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
$pdo = Photobooker\Base::getInstance($db, "usuario");
```

em Conexao:

```
namespace Photobooker;
class Conexao
{
 private static $pdo;
 private function __construct()
{
}

public static function getInstance() {
    $conn = require(__DIR__ . '/../dbconfig.php');
    if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {
        try {
            self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$conn[host]; dbname=$conn[dbname]", $conn['user'], $conn['pass']);
            self::$pdo = new PDO("pgsql:host=$conn[host]; dbname=$conn[dbname]", $conn['user'], $conn['pass']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    return self::$pdo;
 }
 }
```

e em Base:

```
include_once "Conexao.php";

$db = Photobooker\Conexao::getInstance();
class Base {

private $pdo = null;  // Atributo para guardar uma conexão PDO
private $tabela = null;  // Atributo onde será guardado o nome da tabela
private static $crud = null;  // Atributo estático que contém uma instância da própria classe
public $nRows = null;
```

E agora o erro que retorna é:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Photobooker\PDO' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\class\Conexao.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\class\Base.php(6): Photobooker\Conexao::getInstance() #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(440): include('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile('C:\\Apache24\\htd...') #3 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass('Photobooker\\Bas...') #4 C:\Apache24\htdocs\cadUsuario.php(8): spl_autoload_call('Photobooker\\Bas...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\class\Conexao.php on line 19
```

Caso eu adicione em Conexão:

```
use PDO;
```

O erro muda para:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Photobooker\Base' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cadUsuario.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\cadUsuario.php on line 8
```

Comment: Está chamando o autoload 2 vezes?

Comment: Mas nem existe a classe `Base`. O método `getInstance` está declarado em `Conexao`. Base é, de fato uma classe? E não esqueça dos *namespaces*, se seu arquivo `cadUsuario` não pertencer ao mesmo `namespace`, as classes devem ser instanciadas com `Photobooker\Base`.

Comment: @Maurivan O autoload dentro da classe Base, é porque ela utiliza um metodo de outra classe, é melhor importar essa classe direto?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss a classe Base existe sim, é que não coloquei toda ela ali, coloquei soh o "cabeçalho".
cadUsuario no caso é o controller pro cadastro dos usuarios. Mas vou fazer as alterações aqui.

Comment: O autoload está aí justamente para evitar a importação de classes a todo instante. Assista o video do link para melhor entendimento e utilização do autoload e namespace. https://youtu.be/UeCVTTtRmGE

Comment: @Maurivan ótimo, me esclareceu bastante. Obrigado pelo help!